# Access logs outside docker containers

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I run an algorithm using the command "docker-compose up" on a cloud server.  One of the services (productionbackend) writes logs as part of its execution, in a location inside its container (./logs/Log_< UTCTIMENOW >.txt).

I know I can use the 'docker logs' command to inspect logs when the service runs, but once it is stopped using 'docker-compose down', logs are lost forever (as the container is destroyed).

So I guess I would like to 'mount' a volume to my docker compose file, and redirect the output of that log.txt file to the ~ directory, outside the container.  This is what my directory tree looks like:

I tried all kind of combinations in the docker compose file, without success.

For instance, adding the below failed.

```
volumes:
- type: volume  # Also tried `bind` type and other syntaxes
- ./logs:/productionbackend/logs


.
├── docker-compose.yaml #THIS IS THE DOCKER-COMPOSE FILE STARTING MY SERVICES
├── productionfrontend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── database.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   └── requirements.txt
│   └── docker-compose.yaml
└── productionbackend
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── backend.py
    ├── logs
    │   ├── Log_03_Jun_14.18.19_GMT.txt
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── settings
    │   └── somefile.py
     ........
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For next:

```
volumes:
- type: volume  # Also tried `bind` type and other syntaxes
- ./logs:/productionbackend/logs
```

I don't know if it's your typo or others, but it seems this grammar is strange, see [official grammar](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)

Next I give a minimal example which could work for your reference:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    image: alpine
    container_name: my_try
    volumes:
      - ./log_on_host:/productionbackend/logs
    command: sh -c 'echo "hi" > /productionbackend/logs/my_log.txt'
```

And next is the execution history:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/abc$ ls
docker-compose.yaml
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/abc$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "abc_default" with the default driver
Creating my_try ... done
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/abc$ docker-compose down
Removing my_try ... done
Removing network abc_default
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/abc$ ls
docker-compose.yaml  log_on_host
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/abc$ cat log_on_host/my_log.txt
hi
```

From above, you can see although the container my_try has been destroyed, we still can see the log `my_log.txt` which has the content `hi` on host. You need to modify yours similar like above minimal example, just FYI.

Comment: Hi atline,  Thank you for the instructive answer.  I found out:  The issue is a python one, as when I interrupt the service (CTRL-C), not only the `finally` clause of my backend.py does not execute, but apparently the log does not get written to the `log_on_host` directory either (Although I can get the `command` executed in my_log.txt, like in your example).  So the issue is still unresolved, it must have to do with the way Docker gracefully exits backend.py (Without writing to file and executing my `finally` clause).  Any ideas?

Comment: If possible to add `-u` when execute python script? Like `python -u test.py`?

Comment: It is:                       -u     : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;
         this option has no effect on stdin; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x

Comment: The Dockerfile became CMD ["python", "-u", "backend.py"] but it did not put the log file in the expected folder (after rebuilding the image)

Comment: I'm a little lost here, you want the output to be written to file at once, then what it's related with stdin? As you have confirmed this could related to python output, could you write a minimal question which could let all guys reproduce your issue easily? Also I add `python` tag for you in case needed.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly fine, my bad.  The backend Dockerfile had the following:                                                                                                                 ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

Comment: Hence the following in the Docker-compose file works just fine:                                         volumes:
      - ./log_on_host:/code/logs